# Why doesn't a While Loop inside a For Loop work in my program?

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop

I should make a program where I should print out the short (compressed word), having the long one. For an example: **8S2Q3R** is short for **SSSSSSSSQQRRR**. Now, I made this short program, which doesn't work (loops endlessly). I'm pretty sure I shouldn't be putting a *while-loop* inside a *for-loop*, but I'm not sure how exactly to fix this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char word[80];
    cin >> word;
    int length = strlen(word);
    int counter = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {{
        while (word[i] == word[i + 1]) {
            counter++;
        }
        cout << counter << word[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Similarly, if I have to print out a long word having a short one, I made a program which also doesn't work (output is a bunch of hieroglyphs):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int number = 0;

bool Number(char c) {
    switch(c) {
    case '1':
        number = 1;
        return true;
        break;
    case '2':
        number = 2;
        return true;
        break;
    case '3':
        number = 3;
        return true;
        break;
    case '4':
        number = 4;
        return true;
        break;
    case '5':
        number = 5;
        return true;
        break;
    case '6':
        number = 6;
        return true;
        break;
    case '7':
        number = 7;
        return true;
        break;
    case '8':
        number = 8;
        return true;
        break;
    case '9':
        number = 9;
        return true;
        break;
    case '0':
        number = 0;
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{

    char word[80];
    cin >> word;
    int length = strlen(word);
    int counter = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (Number(word[i])) {
            for (int j = 0; j < number; i++) {
                cout << word[i];
            }
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By *doesn't work*, do you mean *doesn't compile*?

Comment: You are not incrementing "i" in your while loop so it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: the for loop should go till i < length-1 since you are accessing word[i+1]

Comment: Match curly braces firstly

Comment: The `for` loop in your second program doesn't change `j`, so the truth value of the condition never changes.

Comment: If you never change your loop condition in your loop you will loop forever (or never).

Comment: Advice -- Your `Number` function would have been shortened considerably if you observed that you are repeating the code over and over again:  It boils down to this: `{ int num = c - '0'; if (num >= 0 && num <= 9)  {number = num; return true;}  return false; }`

Comment: Also, you are not re-initialising `counter` to `1` when you should. So it just gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: @ArdaKara This is the answer I’ve been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want but I assumed that there can be 2 or more consecutive digits and only one character after the digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int
main ()
{
    char word[80];
    char out[128];
    char temp[10];
    cin >> word;

    int len = strlen (word);

    int index = 0;
    int numindex = 0;
    int count;
    while (index < len) {
        while (word[index] >= '0' && word[index] <= '9') {
            temp[numindex++] = word[index++];
        }
        temp[numindex] = 0;
        count = atoi (temp);

        numindex = 0;
        char ch = word[index++];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            out[i] = ch;
        }
        out[count] = 0;
        cout << out;
    }

    return 0;
}
```